# Queryset only on the first foreign key linked to the instance

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Let's say for example I have these models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('name'))


class Keyword(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('name'))
    person = models.ForeignKey('Keyword', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'd like to query on the Person model, where we filter on ONLY the first keyword linked to that person.

The keyword list is always ordered.

So for example:

Person John doe has 3 keyword (Programming, Travel, Family)

I'd like to do something like this (if this is possible)

```
Person.objects.filter(keyword_"first"="Programming")
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "first". The `Keyword`s are *unordered* for a `Person`.

Comment: use a created_datetime column and use order by asceding then slice the query set with first item [:1]

Comment: For this example yes, But not where I'd like to implement it. the list is always ordered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate with [**`.alias(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias) with a [**`Subquery`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions), and then filter:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

class Person.objects.alias(
    first_keyword=Subquery(
        Keyword.objects.filter(
            person=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('value')[:1]
    )
).filter(
    first_keyword='Programming'
)
```

But models are by default *unordered*: that means that each time a different keyword can be the first. Only if you have a column and an [**`ordering`** option <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering), or an [**`.order_by(…)`** clause <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) in the subquery, it is guaranteed that a certain item will be the first keyword.

You can make the filtering optional with a field `only_first` that will filter on the first item if `True` and on all items if `False`:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Q, Subquery

class Person.objects.alias(
    first_keyword=Subquery(
        Keyword.objects.filter(
            person=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('value')[:1]
    )
).filter(
    Q(first_keyword='Programming') |
    Q(only_first=False, keyword__value='Programming')
)
```

Comment: Is there any expansion i can do with this? such as, if the Person has a booleanfield that is set to True: only filter on first keyword. If it is False: filter on all keywords? (sorry for making this extremly harder)

Comment: @Yorbjörn: see edit.